# open a notification in webview

Tags: android, webview, notifications

I am working on an application and i want that my notification should be opened in a         webview please help.
or
I want that my application should respond to that notification.

Comment: Did you tried anything ?

Comment: @user1633165: your question is not clear at all, and not providing anything that's points you have any problem. if you know what is webView, what is notification - you should not have problem at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just start intent calling an activity which will open your url in webView

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the new InAppBrowser function in Cordova 2.3.0 (newest version) is something you looking for.
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#InAppBrowser

```
<plugin name="InAppBrowser" value="org.apache.cordova.InAppBrowser" />
```

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>InAppBrowser.addEventListener Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.3.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for Cordova to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // Cordova is ready
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
         var ref = window.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=yes');
         ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function() { alert('start: ' + event.url); });
         ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function() { alert('stop: ' + event.url); });
         ref.addEventListener('exit', function() { alert(event.type); });
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```